# Why does the count button not work on my Oracle APEX form?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I need to make 2 buttons that add and remove the amount of products on an orderline.

[image: the orderline form page.]

What I need to do is when I press a the plus or minus button it should increase or decrease the number on amount.

I have tried to add JavaScript in the global functions and add the JavaScript via a dynamic action on the buttons but it does't seem to work

Here is my page in the editor:
[image]
and here is the global function page:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the apex javascript apis this can be done in a much more declarative way. No need for event listeners (the dynamic action will create those for you) or setting values manually. The code will be a lot more maintainable. Only code needed is the one in the example below (for a single button - the button to substract should be trivial)

Create a dynamic action on click of button with true action of type "execute javascript code" with code:

```
let num;
if (apex.item( "P11_AMOUNT" ).isEmpty()) {
  num = 0;
} else {
  num = parseInt(apex.item( "P11_AMOUNT" ).getValue());
}  
apex.item( "P11_AMOUNT" ).setValue(num + 1);
```

Code above is for the "increment" button.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes around the variable (so it is a variable and not a string literal):

```js
let P11_AMOUNT = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    P11_AMOUNT += 1;
    int.innerHTML = P11_AMOUNT;
});

remove.addEventListener('click', function(){
    P11_AMOUNT -= 1;
    int.innerHTML = P11_AMOUNT;
});
```